# Difference between static file on server and returning this file via HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

What I don't understand is how browsers make difference between these two:

```
1 http://server.com/filename.plist
2 http://server.com/servletGetFile/filename  that returns the same file
```

in the response.

My real problem is that when I upload the file and access it with it's name from safari then I manage to install the app, but when the link is pointing to the servlet that returns this same file safari just doesn't do anything.

So is it possiblle to make the java servlet to return the file as it is static content on the server?

Here are both responses (1 for static file and second via servlet:

```
Responce headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 14:32:42 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2820
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.02
======================================
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Ayudo_v.1.plist"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 14:36:37 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2-14
```

Comment: What does "manage to install the app" mean? My best guess is that for a static file, the application server is guessing/sniffing the file type and sending a `Content-Type` header, but that's not happening when the servlet sends the file. Perhaps look at the headers (e.g., the network inspector on Firefox).

Comment: @bkail I'm developing inhouse server. On this server I'm uploading .plist file for every iOS app. So when I click on link that is pointing to static file , then safari downloads this .plist file, reads in this file where is the .ipa file(the iOS app ) and then installs it. Using servlet it's not working. I hope it's more clear not. If not then I'll try to describe it again.

Comment: My best guess is the `Content-Disposition` header, but I don't know.  The `Content-Type` difference also seems odd, but I'm not familiar with plist files.  I would try changing the servlet one header at a time to match the static file.

Comment: please post your servlet code

Comment: sorry guys. The problem was in the link. Seems that safari couldn't open it so that is why the servlet wasn't call at all (most probably because of the & ). May be I should delete this question, but at least I learned something. There is not other dependency, but only and only the headers , so there is no way for the client side to differentiate between static and non static file if you set appropriate headers